# Как получить данные из родительского блока на jquery?

Tags: jquery

Есть HTML

```
<div class="new_item">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" id="url" class="form-control">
  <a href="#" class="save">Сохранить</a>
</div>
<div class="new_item">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" id="url" class="form-control">
  <a href="#" class="save">Сохранить</a>
</div>
```

Уникальный ID блоку установить не представляется возможным.
Как получить содержимое input блока в котором был произведен клик по ссылке `<a href="#" class="save">Сохранить</a>`?

```
    Пробывал так:
    $('body').on('click','.new_item a#save', function(){
       alert($(this).parent('input#name').val());
       alert($(this).parent('input#url').val());
    });
   //Возвращает undefined
```

Comment: В HTML у вас "new_item" и "save" - это классы, а селекторы в jQuery указывают на ID. Это вы на форуме опечатку сделали или так и есть в реале?

Comment: Опечатка, щас исправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
   alert($(this).parent().find('#name').val());
   alert($(this).parent().find('#url').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените id на class и используйте функцию siblings.

Примерно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/7pgbttw4/)

```
<div class="new_item">
  <input type="text" class="name" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" class="url" class="form-control">
  <a href="#" class="save">Сохранить</a>
</div>

<div class="new_item">
  <input type="text" class="name" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" class="url" class="form-control">
  <a href="#" class="save">Сохранить</a>
</div>

$('a').on('click', 
        function() {
            alert($(this).siblings('.name').val());    
        })
```